# Get a 64 bit value with a 32 bit address

Tags: c

I have a 32 bit address

```
uint32_t ptrToValue;
```

and I want to have a 64 bit value from this memory place.

If I do like this

```
uint64_t value = *(uint64_t*) ptrToValue;
```

I get an warning "makes a pointer of a different integer size"

How can I handle that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you're compiling 64-bit code, this is absolutely invalid.

Comment: I work on a PPC with 32bit long addresses and I need to store and read a 64bit value

Comment: so why don't you store it as a 64 bit value (uint64_t)?

Comment: @Peter and the address model has *what* do to with that? how is that effecting being able to read 8 bytes of data (at a 32bit address) vs. 4 bytes of bytes of data (at a 32bit address)?

Comment: @Peter *Your* PPC may have 32-bit long addresses, however the development of C came about as a need to write *portable* software. In portable software, you should *not* convert a pointer to a uint32_t. Now, please answer Mysticial's question: Why do you want to make your software non-portable? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Peter, could you confirm that `ptrToValue` is really declared as `uint32_t`, and not as `uint32_t*`? In other words, you really store the address in an integer, rather than using a pointer type. Is that correct?

Comment: The warning I get is "cast to pointer from integer of different size". Please quote the warning *exactly*; don't try to summarize it. The warning indicates that pointers on your system are not 32 bits; most likely they're 64 bits. That implies that you *can't* store a valid pointer in a `uint32_t` object. Pointers are not integers. Why isn't your pointer stored in an object of pointer type? Where did the pointer value come from? It's likely that you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: OP writes in the 3rd comment that he is indeed using a PPC with 32bit pointers and just wants to read a 64bit value there.

Answer (score 3):

Use an integer type of the right size: `intptr_t`. This is an integral type that is guaranteed to be convertible to a pointer and back.

Comment: +1 It is also one of only two (the other being `uintptr_t`) that are standard-defined, though there is no guarantee they are provided by your implementation (C99 §7.20.1.4). If non-pointer storage of a pointer is needed, this is the way to do it.

Comment: hi @nneonneo i dont think OP wants to store a pointer in an int, his 3rd comment is that he is using a PPC with 32bit addresses and just wants to store a 64bit value.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 32 bit address

Probably you mean that you have a pointer to 32 bits (4 bytes) of memory.

> uint32_t ptrToValue;

You mean this?:

> uint32_t* ptrToValue;

When you added that * then the warning should go away.

As jogojapan mentions in the comment this ignores the alignment issue, so let me explain.

If the combined 64bit value is on a 64bit boundary (a byte-address divisible by 8) then there is no problem if you want to cast the pointer and read/write the 64bit at once. However if it is not, **and** your machine does not support un-aligned access, then bad things happen (ie program crash).

If you want the code to work on any machine (at least those that *can* store 64bits at once) you would have to use a union:

```
typedef union {
    uint32_t b32[2];
    uint64_t b64[1];
} bits64;
```

You can then declare a variable of type `bytes8` and use `b32[0]` and `b32[1]` or `b64[0]` depending on whether you want to interpret it as 32bit or 64bit value.

Comment: But whether casting `uint32_t*` to `uint64_t*` is ok still depends on alignment and, as soon as you dereference that pointer, on whether there is really a `uint64_t` stored at that address.